# Flutter rebuild a TweenAnimationBuilder

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I want to make a flipping animation with TweenAnimationBuilder, a container will flip over and change the color. I want to add a button when user click on it, the container will flip over again and change into another colour.

Here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  bool isBack = true;

  Color backColor = Colors.green;
  Color topColor = Colors.red;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              box(),
              SizedBox(height: 10),
              ElevatedButton(
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    minimumSize: Size(25, 10),
                    elevation: 10,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      backColor = Colors.red;
                      topColor = Colors.blue;
                    });
                  },
                  child:
                      Text('change to blue', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16))),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget box() {
    print('building');
    return TweenAnimationBuilder(
        tween: Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: pi),
        duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
        builder: (BuildContext context, double value, _) {
          print(value);
          if (value >= (pi / 2)) {
            isBack = false;
          } else {
            isBack = true;
          }
          return (Transform(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            transform: Matrix4.identity()
              ..setEntry(3, 2, 0.001)
              ..rotateY(value),
            child: Container(
                width: 100,
                height: 100,
                child: isBack
                    ? Container(
                        color: backColor,
                      )
                    : Transform(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        transform: Matrix4.identity()
                          ..rotateY(
                              pi),
                        child: Container(
                          color: topColor,
                        ),
                      ) 
                ),
          ));
        });
  }
}
```

At the first build, the tween value will start from the beginning:

```
building
0
0
0
0.13080335172486462
0.19619246121668257
0.2180893620122034
...
3.141592653589793
```

but when I click on the button to change the color, it will not start again from the begin value, it just stays at 3.14:

```
building
3.141592653589793
```

Right now the button will only change the color of the container, but it will not flip again.

I suppose after the setstate function, the tween value will restart again at 0, why won't it do so?
Can anybody explain it please?

Comment: do you want to reverse the animation?

Comment: No I just want it to rebuild again, Tween value  to start again from the begin value, with same rotating direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is an `AnimationController` and `AnimatedBuilder` to control the animation.

```dart
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  bool isBack = true;

  Color backColor = Colors.blue;
  Color topColor = Colors.red;
  late AnimationController _animationController;
  late Animation _rotationAnimation;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _animationController =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: const Duration(seconds: 1));

    _rotationAnimation =
        Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: pi).animate(_animationController);

     _animationController.forward();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              box(),
              SizedBox(height: 10),
              ElevatedButton(
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    minimumSize: Size(25, 10),
                    elevation: 10,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      backColor = Colors.red;
                      topColor = Colors.blue;
                    });
                    // if (_animationController.isDismissed) {
                    //   _animationController.forward();
                    // } else if (_animationController.isCompleted) {
                    //   _animationController.reverse();
                    // }
                    _animationController.forward(from: 0.0);
                  },
                  child:
                      Text('change to blue', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16))),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget box() {
    return AnimatedBuilder(
        animation: _animationController,
        // tween: Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: pi),
        // duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
        builder: (_, __) {
          // print(value);
          if (_rotationAnimation.value >= (pi / 2)) {
            isBack = false;
          } else {
            isBack = true;
          }
          return Transform(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            transform: Matrix4.identity()
              ..setEntry(3, 2, 0.001)
              ..rotateY(_rotationAnimation.value),
            child: Container(
              width: 100,
              height: 100,
              child: isBack
                  ? Container(
                      color: backColor,
                    )
                  : Transform(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      transform: Matrix4.identity()..rotateY(pi),
                      child: Container(
                        color: topColor,
                      ),
                    ),
            ),
          );
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort but unfortunately it isn't what I wanted. I want it to flip once in the first build, and flip again with the same direction when clicking on the button, not reversing it. I just want to know how to restart the tween value after the first build, setstate doesn't seemed working

Comment: That is also possible. first, you have to `_animationController.forward();` inside `initState` this will flip when it's build. Then inside onTap callback call this `_animationController.forward(from: 0.0);`

Comment: But still it will not flip in the first build, it flips only when I click the button

Comment: It's actually flipping when it's first built. Did you copy my updated answer? It should work.

Comment: How would you change that so it will be a slide in from top animation?

Answer (score 0):

You can just give a key to the TweenAnimationBuilder.

```
TweenAnimationBuilder<T>(
         key: UniqueKey(),
         duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 700),
```

The reason in your case is: Flutter is not creating a new element for the new TweenAnimationBuilder widget, this is for performance.